# DataView Rowfilter Expression C#

Tags: c#, dataview, rowfilter

I am having a dataTable in which one of the columns is of a specific type of object say typeOf(A) - A being my custom class. The class A is having a text property and other properties like bool. From user or external code I get only the text value to be used in RowFilter for Filtering, in the below example I will get "cat" as my filter to be used. Using this how to create the RowFilterExpression?

```
class A
{
   public string Text{get;set;}
   public bool isReadonly {get;set;}
} 

DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("col1", typeOf(A));
table.Rows.Add(new A{Text = "cat", isReadOnly = true,})
table.Rows.Add(new A{Text = "dog", isReadOnly = false,})

string filter = "cat";

DataView dataView = new DataView(table);
dataView.RowFilter = "[col1]='"+filter+"'";
```

The above expression doesnot work because it tries to match it to the object in cell. how to filter out the 1st row alone using this filter expression?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

overriding object ToString method like this :

```
class A
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool isReadonly { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Text;
    }
}
```

and you can use :

```
dataView.RowFilter = string.Format("Convert([col1], 'System.String') = '{0}'", filter);
```

Comment: It only works if you also implement the ToString method from the other answer. This compiles and executes but it doesnt actually return any results.

Comment: Thanks for remak, you are right, i have change my code.

Comment: Your update obviously works now, however the convert to string in the filter is not required as this is done by default.

Comment: Because its just a copy of the other persons answer and you dont need to convert.

Comment: But the first part of code doesnt work for me alone, it work with both

Comment: I had already overridden the ToString in my code. It never worked. The expression in the rowfilter made the difference. Without that convert it never worked. Thanks Abdellah OUMGHAR!

Comment: One more question, This convert to string in the rowFilter expression is causing precision loss when converting the float or double values in the column to string. Whereas the filter may be precise to the last decimal. Because of this it will never return me the filtered rows even if the filter exists in the table. any idea what tweaking should be done?

Comment: Also what can we do about the casing?. what should be added in the syntax so that the casing is not taken into account while trying to  filter.

Comment: You can do : `table.CaseSensitive = false;`

Comment: that helped. Thankyou. Any idea what to do about the float values precision problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try overriding `ToString` method in your object and then your current filtering code should work

```
class A
{
   public string Text{get;set;}
   public bool isReadonly {get;set;}

   public override string ToString()
   {
      return this.Text;
   }
}
```

Comment: The overridden ToString was always there in my tests but it never helped in the filtering the trick was in the rowFilter expression. Thanks anyways.

Comment: But the code you posted does not have overridden `ToString` method, neither you mentioned you have it in your tests

Comment: But good its working for you now! However it worked for me when I tested even with overridden `ToString` method alone.